# Artin approximation of a diagram

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, schemes, etale-covers

Let consider $f:(X,x)\to (Z,z)$ and $g:(Y,y)\to (Z,z)$ morphisms of pointed $k$-schemes of finite type ($k$ is a field). Suppose that there exists a map on the level of formal neighborhoods $\phi:X_{x}\to Y_{y}$ that makes the corresponding diagram of formal neighborhoods commute.

Let $N$ be an integer.
Can we approximate $\phi$ by a map $\phi'$ up to order $N$, such that $g\circ\phi'=f$  (allowing some étale neighborhoods)?

---

Comment: What do you mean by approximate? Whether there exists a $\phi'$ in some etale neighborhoods inducing $\phi$ upon completion? Then the answer is no as we can take $Z$ to be a point, $(X, x)=(\mathbb{A}^1, 0)$, $(Y, y) = (\mathbb{A}^1, 1)$ and $\phi = \exp$. Or approximate up to order $N$ for any given $N$? Then I think the answer is yes, because we can apply approximation to the graph of $\phi$.

Comment: approximate up to order $N$ but although such that the diagram commutes.

Comment: Could you make the statement of your question more precise?

Answer (score 2):

This question is almost literally what Artin proved in Algebraic approximation of structures over complete local rings. Read the article and then come back. (Note that by base change you can assume $X = Z$.)